# Animated gif on button stops after moving (redrawing) the form

Tags: c#, winforms, gif, animated-gif

I have an animated gif placed on the button. It's animating ok (most of the times :P) but when the windows is redrawn (repainted) the animation stops. I have tried to refresh the button (button.Refresh() ) while handling Paint event but it didn't solve the issue. \

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: I have tested this, and the animation doesn't stop when my window is redrawn.

Do you do other things when handling the onPaint event?  Have you tried it without overriding the onPaint?

Comment: BackgroundWorker is working (but that's another thread). Animation stops working when I move the window. Also sometimes animation just doesn't start :/ (p.s. this button with animation is not visible until clicking another button, so before activation it's both disabled and unvisible).

Comment: After some consideration - it might be windows 7 compatibility issue I will need to test it on xp machine later. It's not so important issue though.

Comment: I have something similar happening. An animated GIF on an MDI Form occassionally stops animating. Dragging the MDI form off to the side of its container (so that the GIF is not visible) then dragging it back in to view makes the animation start playing again. I'm using Windows Vista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I am mistaken, but I think the issue is that it stops animating not when the form is redrawn, but when the animated object is obscured by another window. This is intended behavior; the bug is that in Windows Vista and Windows 7, the display is composited, so even though the window was 'obscured' it was never truly obscured, and it will never receive paint messages when un-obscured which will kick the animation back in.

This bug appears to affect any ButtonBase-derived control with an animated object.

The issue is the Control.IsWindowObscured function. It will return true. You can see in the ButtonBase.cs file, at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.OnFrameChanged, there is a line of code at the very end that says:

```
if (IsWindowObscured) {
 StopAnimate();
 return;
}
```

and therein lies the problem.

FYI, OnFrameChanged is called from the ImageAnimator thread. This is the callback that is specified in ImageAnimator.Animate(image, eventhandler). ButtonBase sets this up in the private void Animate(bool animate) function. The ImageAnimator thread polls every 50ms and checks to see if a new frame is necessary for any of the images it is monitoring; if so, it sets a flag to have the control invalidated and the new frame drawn.

Since this is inaccessible to us, I don't think there is much we can do about it. As a workaround, I implemented a timer in my form that invalidates the control every 500ms, so it will force it to restart if it had previously stopped. It is quite annoying that we can't override or even access it. I'm afraid the only solution is the hack above, or to create or use a control created by yourself or a third-party.

To clarify -- this is only a problem on Windows Vista or Windows 7 using desktop composition. The issue is that windows are never truly obscured, like they are when not using desktop composition. They are always buffered by the window manager. (There are special layered windows in windows 2000+, but ignore that for now). Previously, the parts of a window were not available if they were not on the screen or obscured by another window. When they came back into view, by changing focus or position etc, then the system will notify that area to repaint itself. However when using desktop composition, the repainting is never required, since the actual contents of the window are buffered elsewhere. This is why the window previews work in the taskbar, and Flip-3d, for example. The side effect is that code that expects to get a paint message when it is visible once again after being obscured will fail. The ButtonBase code expects to recieve a paint message once it comes back into view, which will start the animation again. And therefore, this optimization became a bug.

The issue should be reported in Microsoft Connect, though it is unlikely to be resolved.

Comment: Thx for in depth explanation. My problem somehow was fixed by ... hmm.. don't really know what exactly - updating my VS, changing the gif. I basically gave up and after countless changes in code and gif it finally started working how I wanted :P